# Rewrite dynamic query string having %20

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have these rewrite rules that work for me thanks to @anubhava.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+players/player\.php\?name=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ Football-Players/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^Football-Players/([^/]+)/?$ players/player.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I need also to replace `%20` to `-` in the name parameter. `Cristiano%20Ronaldo` to be rewritten to `Cristiano-Ronaldo`.

Can I make it in the rewrite rule above or I need to do something else?

Comment: You need 1 more rule for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one `%20` to be replaced then following will work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+players/player\.php\?name=([^\%20]+)\%20([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ Football-Players/%1-%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+players/player\.php\?name=([^&\s\%20]+)[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ Football-Players/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^Football-Players/([^-]+)-([^/-]+)/?$ players/player.php?name=$1\%20$2  [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^Football-Players/([^/-]+)/?$ players/player.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Yes that work but now $1 parameter is Crisriano-Ronaldo right? In my sql is Cristiano Ronaldo and i can`t extract information by the name parameter.

Comment: oh so you want space again in player.php?

Comment: i guess this is the problem. I make the site by my own from the scratch with no experience and read lot of books and internet comments and i`am getting confused. Now i understand i never in first place had to leave spaces in sql filed.

Comment: Try edited code now. Yes that so true to not to allow spaced in names that can be part of URLs.